# Get a object data with click in v-for Div

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuex

I have a div with v-for and i want get the object value which div i clicked. I tried to show in data when i click the div with alert but it didn't work. Can you help me to solve this situation.

```
<div id="ticketContent" v-for="ticket in tickets" @click="getTicketInformations">
              <h5> Ticket : {{ ticket.ticketID }}</h5>
              <p>Ticket Number : {{ticket.ticketNumber}}</p>
              <p>Start Date : {{ticket.startDate}}</p>
              <p>Expire Date : {{ticket.expireDate}}</p>
              <p>Hours : {{ ticket.hours }} </p>
            </div>

state : {
   tickets :[
            {"ticketID":1001,
            "ticketNumber":"2783sA",
            "startDate":"05/10/2018",
            "expireDate":"10/21/2022",
            "hours":"08:00-22:00"},
            {"ticketID":1002,
            "ticketNumber":"8a210j",
            "startDate":"01/03/2018",
            "expireDate":"01/03/2020",
            "hours":"14:00-18:00"},
            {"ticketID":1003,
            "ticketNumber":"L90Np1",
            "startDate":"10/01/2015",
            "expireDate":"10/01/2020",
            "hours":"10:00-20:00"},
            {"ticketID":1004,
            "ticketNumber":"L90Np1",
            "startDate":"05/01/2015",
            "expireDate":"05/01/2016",
            "hours":"15:00-23:00"}],
}
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters({
        tickets : 'tickets'
      }),
    },
    methods : {
      getTicketInformations(){
        alert(ticket)
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Guys i found. Send ticket object with my function and then get data on method worked for me

Comment: `silentcontrol`, yes, that's the way. Add the param to your click method: `@click="getTicketInformations(ticket)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add add selectedTicket property to model and then pass ticket instance to showTicket method in click event.

```html
<script src="http://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<style>
    .ticket{padding:5px; border-bottom:1px solid lightblue}
</style>

<div id="app" style="width:100vw">
    Tickets:
    <div class="ticket" v-for="ticket in tickets"
         v-bind:key="ticketID"
         @click="showTicket(ticket)">
        {{ticket.ticketNumber}}
    </div>
    <br/>
    Selected Ticket:
    <div>{{selectedTicket}}</div>

</div>

<script>
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data() {
        return {
            selectedTicket: null,
            tickets: [
                {
                    "ticketID": 1001,
                    "ticketNumber": "2783sA",
                    "startDate": "05/10/2018",
                    "expireDate": "10/21/2022",
                    "hours": "08:00-22:00"
                },
                {
                    "ticketID": 1002,
                    "ticketNumber": "8a210j",
                    "startDate": "01/03/2018",
                    "expireDate": "01/03/2020",
                    "hours": "14:00-18:00"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        showTicket(ticket) {
            this.selectedTicket = ticket;
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

change the vfor

```
<div id="ticketContent_(index)" v-for="(ticket, index) in tickets" @click="getTicketInformations(index)">
```

and the method:

```
getTicketInformations(index){
        alert("clicked on ->" + document.getElementById(ticketContent_' + index + '))
      }
```